# how to create soap envelope , with help of json request body in api call

Tags: python, soapui, soap-client

I am trying to create saop envelope with the help of json request body . I am not allowed to hardcode the xml with f string of pyhton since elements in the xml can vary in accordance with the request body of json

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope        xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <tem:Download>
     <tem:ID2>1</tem:ID2>
     <tem:ID>1</tem:ID>
     <tem:CNO>466</tem:CNO>
     <tem:Type>01</tem:Type>
    </tem:DownloadCKYCData>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to use f string , but I am looking for better alternative .  I have to use it as request body for my get api

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the same f strings to replace the values accordingly? and you aren't hardcoding the values here:

```
# you'll have to extract these values beforehand before using those below

id2 = someval
id = someval
cno = someval
type = someval

body = f"""
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope        xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <tem:Download>
     <tem:ID2>{id2}</tem:ID2>  
     <tem:ID>{id}</tem:ID>
     <tem:CNO>{cno}</tem:CNO>
     <tem:Type>{type}</tem:Type>
    </tem:DownloadCKYCData>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>"""

# I'm assuming that you're using the requests library to perform the http call
response = requests.get(url,data=body,headers=headers)
```

Comment: I am not thinkig to hardcode the xml with f string , please help me with some other alternative

Comment: @SatyamGupta I'm not sure how else you can dynamically populate your xml body